# Azure Storage - Reason BlobInventoryPolicy is not supported for the account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

How can I use Blob inventory? Why does my account not support BlobInventoryPolicy?

```
Could not add blob inventory rule 'myRule' for account 'mystorage'. Reason BlobInventoryPolicy is not supported for the account.
```

Here is my account.

[image]

Comment: What’s the kind of your storage account?

Comment: I have updated the description.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-inventory-how-to?tabs=azure-portal) "Versions and snapshots must be enabled on the account to save a new rule with the corresponding option enabled." Did you activate these features?

Comment: As per the storage account type and settings you are using  you should be able to enable, i just tried and it worked in my account. could you please clear browser cache and give a try once.

Comment: I have checked that versions and snapshots are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I tested my environment, and I was able to enable blob inventory for storage account type you are using

- Created storage account with Storage accountv2(general Purpose v2)
- Created containers with private access
- And then selected  blob inventory under data management click on it and then click on add rule>>give a name and select the container and select the object type for inventory(blob/container) and then select blob types, select blob sub type as require and fill the remaining details and save
  I can see that rule is added with out any error

[image]

[image]